# Parsing CSV file into graph xcode

Tags: arrays, xcode, csv, graph, core-plot

I followed an online tutorial about plotting graphs using Core plot.

It works just fine. But I want to put my own data in the graph via CSV file.
This is the way it looks now.

It is called from another file, so the data shown, is not in the same file as the configuration of the graph.

```
- (NSArray *)weeklyGoogPrices
{
static NSArray *prices = nil;
if (!prices)
{
    prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:597.60], 
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:601.27], 
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:609.72],
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:615.47], 
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:614.98],                   
              nil];
}
return prices;
}
```

I have used this way to parse in my CSV file. And I can see it works just fine, because when I print out row using NSLog it appears in the console.

```
NSString *hejhej = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tis" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *nyt = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:hejhej encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableArray *row= [[nyt componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@", row);
```

My idea was to use the addObject: function an then just add the functions of row into the prices array. But i can't figure out how to do that, since I can't parse the CSV file inside the - (NSArray *) weeklyGoogPrices, or if it even would work.

My CSV file contains two rows with random numbers in it, like: 
1,25
2,32
3,54
etc...

I hope I'd made my self clear, and that somebody can help me :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Use `-componentsSeparatedByString:` on each row to split the values at the commas. If you know there are no blanks or missing values, you might be able to cheat and return the string values from your datasource. If not, convert each one to a double or decimal value (or `nil`, `NSNull`, or NAN for missing values) before returning it from the datasource.